# How to move First/Selected order to last in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to move my first order to the bottom of the list and not to delete the first order as well.
here is my code. This is deleting/unset first order as well.

`

```
if (isset($request['defer_order']) && $request['defer_order'] != null) {
            $order_id = $request['defer_order'];

            foreach ($order_items as $key => $order_item) {
                $last = count($order_items);
                if ($order_item->order_id == $order_id) {
                    unset($order_items[$key]);
                    $order_items[$last + 1] = $order_item;

                }
            }


            $order_items = $order_items;

        }
```

`

I am trying to move first order to the bottom of the list.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `unset`, the order is removed from the `array`. You can use the code below instead. It will add your desired order at the end without changing anything in the `array`

```
if (isset($request['defer_order']) && $request['defer_order'] != null) {
    $order_id = $request['defer_order'];

    $order_items = (array)$order_items;

    $myOrder = '';
    foreach ($order_items as $order_item) {
        if ($order_item['order_id'] == $order_id) {
            $myOrder = $order_item;
            unset($order_items[$key]);

            break;
        }
    }

    if ($myOrder != '') {
        $order_items[] = $myOrder;
    }

    $order_items = (object)$order_items;
}
```

**Updated the code as per your requirement**

Comment: @Hasseb it's moving the order to the bottom and creating a new copy. I have 779 records but when I move the record it shows 780.

Comment: it's showing "Undefined index: "